# $\lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)$:convergent $\Rightarrow$ $\lim_{t\to \infty}x'(t)=0$

Tags: analysis

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)\text{ convergent} \Rightarrow \lim_{t\to \infty}x'(t)=0$$
where　$'=\frac{d}{dt}$.

Is this proposition the truth?

Answer (score 1):

No, take $$f(t)=\frac{\sin(t^2)}{t}$$

Then $$f'(t) = 2 \cos(t^2)-\frac{\sin(t^2)}{t^2}$$

And it doesn't converge to 0.

Comment: Thank you. How do it become it if $x(t)$ is a monotone function?

Comment: Still not true. A little harder to explain. I'll give an exemple where your function is not differentiable in some points, but you can imagine the same idea with a smooth function. Let's define the function f as follow : it's 0 everywhere except on $[n-\frac{1}{2^n},n+\frac{1}{2^n}]$ where it's a triangle with height 1 (easier to see with a drawing). Then we take $$F(x) = \int_0^x f(x) dx$$. It's easy to show that F is monotonous and has finite limit (the area of all triangle is the serie $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ )

Comment: How do it become if $x(t)$ is a strictly monotone function?